# Should I install 12.04 or 10.10 on a laptop with 512MB of RAM?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, file-server

I would like to like to install Ubuntu on my old HCL laptop. Its hardware specifications are as follows:

- **Processor:** Intel Dual Core T2080
- **RAM:** 512MB DDR2
- **HDD:** 80GB
- **GPU:** ATI Radeon Xpress Series

I've been running **Windows XP SP3** here for quite a while and recently it has become really slow. Heck, I can't even use Firefox 15 without the occasional 5 min lag.

My question is **should I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or 10.04.4 LTS (Deskop version) on this laptop?**

What I intend to use the laptop for: (after installing Ubuntu)

- 24*7 online seedbox
- Ocassional web surfing
- Basic file server

Thank you for reading this question. Kindly defend your answer.

**EDIT:** Best solution imo:

I've installed Ubuntu Server 12.04. It servers all needs:

- **Transmission**
- Mount external HDDs on boot - your very own **NAS**
- **Samba File Server** to access files from any of your devices

Answer (score 0):

**System requirements**

1. While the minimum memory requirement for 32bit is 384 MB, a minimum of 512 MB is needed for the 64bit installation. On systems with only the bare minimum amount of memory, it is also strongly recommended to use the "Install Ubuntu" option as it uses less memory than the full live session.
2. The Ubuntu 12.04 installation image does not include support for old computers that do not support PAE. If your computer is affected, you can either first install Ubuntu 10.04 or 11.10 and upgrade to 12.04 or you can use the Lubuntu or Xubuntu images. The non-PAE version of the Linux kernel will be dropped completely following the 12.04 release.

Reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements

Comment: Hi VD, thanks for your input. I guess I'll be going with either Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main consideration is your RAM. 512 MB is very borderline. As is, I would say install 10.04 because the GNOME 2 desktop environment will be less resource hungry than the Unity desktop environment of 12.04. Similarly, as @VendettaDroid suggested check out [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) for additional lightweight, Ubuntu compatible options.

Aside from that, maybe check your laptop specs to see if you could increase you RAM? This could actually become a necessity depending upon how heavily it will be used as a file server.

Comment: Exactly mate. Since I'm just using it for a basic seedbox and file-server purpose, I'll restrain myself from upgrading its RAM. A friend suggested Xubuntu. I'm gonna check them out ASAP. Thanks so much for your input.